# How do I correctly use await inside of shorthand if else Javascript statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, kendo-ui

I'm not only making a transition away from jQuery but I am also trying to make my code a lot leaner.  As I work on large scale enterprise applications the amount of jQuery and JavaScript that is being used can reach crisis point.

I want to start working in a better way and using vanilla JavaScript again.  I build applications using the likes of KendoUI and it hinges on jQuery to make it work.  That said, I want to keep the rest of my code as vanilla JavaScript, shorthanded and efficient (asynchronous where appropriate).

I'm trying to achieve the following goals with a JavaScript statement of mine

- Find the tabs container
- Bind an event listener to check the tabs Id when it's event is `shown`
- Load a KendoUI grid asynchronously awaiting it

So, to achieve this in shorthand vanilla JavaScript I did the following.

```
//Find the tabs using the query selector
document.querySelector('#main-tabs')

    //Add an event listener that listens for the `shown` bootstrap tab event
    .addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', (e) => {

        //Take the id of the tab and if the name equals "overview-tab" 
        //then load the grid, if it doesn't then do nothing.
        (e.target.id == "overview-tab") ? load_grid_opportunities() : null;

    });
```

Ok, so from here I went and created my asynchronous function that loads my grid.  I created an async function called `load_grid_opportunities` and then we encounter generic KendoUI jQuery based widget binding.

```
const load_grid_opportunities = async () => {    
    $('#grid_opportunities').kendoGrid({
       //shortened for brevity
    });
}
```

This is where I have gotten to because now I'm wondering, how do I await this async function in my if/else statement?  My first instinct was to simply call `await` inline like this:

```
(e.target.id == "overview-tab") ? await load_grid_opportunities() : null;
```

However, this didn't work as it's an unexpected argument.  I then tried to use parenthesis to encapsulate the request but that didn't work either.

```
(e.target.id == "overview-tab") ? (await load_grid_opportunities()) : null;
```

So, how on earth can I await my function?

Comment: because your callback isn't async. Also in this case a standard `if` block will be more clear, you're not gaining much with the ternary especially since you're not doing anything with the `null`

Comment: I think that's a fair comment, I did start to think about that null more and more and then concluded it was a pointless approach to shorthand it.  Thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To await your function your function must return promise, please see the code below.

```js
function load_grid_opportunities() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $('#grid_opportunities').kendoGrid({
            //shortened for brevity
        });
        resolve();
    });
}

// Now you can call your function

async function doSomething()
{

if (e.target.id == "overview-tab") 
{
    await load_grid_opportunities();
}
}
```

Comment: and the `await` must be called in an async function itself.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's cleared up what I was attempting to do a lot.  Isn't it also the case that you can use the promise and resolve approach in the following manner as wels, something like: `somefunction().then(yay, nay);`

Comment: yes you can do that, but async, await is much cleaner and newer way of doing things, so i would recommend use that.